# Items don't show from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native

I'm using React. I try to map an array with object and to output the name of each object from array {1: Array(8), 2: Array(1)}

```
Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => (
      <Grid item key={cuid()} lg={4} sm={6} xs={12}>
          <Typography variant="subtitle1">{key}</Typography>
          {value.forEach((item) => {
                
                <Typography variant="subtitle1">{item.name}</Typography>
          })}
      </Grid>
      
    ))
```

The value is an Array (8) and Array (1):

Array(8)

```
0: {id: 1, name: 'a'}
1: {id: 2, name: 'b'}
2: {id: 3, name: 'c'}
3: {id: 4, name: 'd'}
4: {id: 5, name: 'e'}
5: {id: 6, name: 'f'}
6: {id: 7, name: 'g'}
7: {id: 8, name: 'h'}
```

Array (1)

```
0: {id: 28, name:'z'}
```

The item.name don't show on my webpage. What should I correct?

Comment: can you paste the console log of what is inside the value

Comment: @vaira I add to my problem.

Comment: In the future, the best way to show data is to use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` That way we don't have to interpret all of the "Array (8)" cruft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of JSX as "always returning something". You are [mapping over](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)
`value`, and since `forEach` does not return anything, you are not seeing anything. Use `map` instead of `forEach`

```
{value.map((item) => {
 return <Typography key={item.id} variant="subtitle1">{item.name}</Typography>
 }
```

Edit: As Vijeeth pointed out, you should also be using a stable key for each item.

Answer (score 1):

do not forget to use key as it is `import` to render every object of  your map.

```
{value.map((item, index) => {
   return <Typography variant="subtitle1" key={index}>{item.name}</Typography>
}
```